# Flutter: "The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null" error when I use the Multiple Selection Dropdown Checkbox?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to use the `DropDown checkbox` to select **multiple** items in Flutter Application and I have fetched the `data` from **Firebase** using **`StreamBuilder`** and used the **multiselect_formfield** package for selecting the value from a **`list`**.

I rewrote the code according to my need and it is giving me a `null` error **while selecting the value**.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you!

Here is the `code` part:

```
  List _myActivities;
  String _myActivitiesResult;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myActivities = [];
    _myActivitiesResult = '';
  }

  Widget _smithName(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _firestore.collection('categories').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        var result = snapshot.data.docs;
        _myActivities = [];
        result.forEach((item){
        _myActivities.add(item.data()['category']);
        }); 
        return new Container(
          child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          MultiSelectFormField(
                      autovalidate: false,
                      title: Text('Category'),
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.length == 0 ? 'Please select one or more category' : null,
                      dataSource: _myActivities,
                      textField: 'category',
                      valueField: 'category',
                      okButtonLabel: 'OK',
                      cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
                      // required: true,
                      hintWidget: Text('Please choose one or more'),
                      initialValue: _myActivities,
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        if (value == null) return;
                        setState(() {
                          _myActivities = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  
                Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                child: Text(_myActivitiesResult),
              )
        ],
      ),
                
    ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("category")
```

Below is the Screenshot of Firebase Database.
[image: Firebase_Screenshot]

Comment: If you could share the error log as well, that'd be great. Please ensure that you share the error log every time.

Comment: `type 'MappedListIterable<QueryDocumentSnapshot, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'` - This is the error I am getting right now and before I was getting null value error.

Comment: Also, I will need a screenshot of the data stored on the FireStore. If I get that, I would be able to answer your question aptly. I have found the problem. I'll be posting it. But I'll have to edit it after I can see the Screenshot.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the Firestore data. Please check and give me a solution.

Comment: result should be a list

Comment: How do I make the Firestore data as a list?

Comment: There's an option to add Lists to Firebase. However, check their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2:**
Make the following changes:

Initialize a new List `res = [];`

```dart
MultiSelectFormField(
                      autovalidate: false,
                      title: Text('Category'),
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.length == 0 ? 'Please select one or more category' : null,
                      dataSource: _myActivities,
                      textField: 'category',
                      valueField: 'category',
                      okButtonLabel: 'OK',
                      cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
                      // required: true,
                      hintWidget: Text('Please choose one or more'),
                      initialValue: res,
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        if (value == null) return;
                        setState(() {
                          res = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  
                Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                child: Text(_myActivitiesResult),
              )
```

Comment: Kindly check the screenshot

Comment: Getting error  - `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`

Comment: Please edit the question with the changes made in the code and the new error you faced.

Comment: Got another error “A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget”

Comment: May I know why do you gave “category” in textfield and valuefield ?

Comment: If you check the example given in the package document, you will find that in the `dataSource` field, a map is passed. The map contains certain values. Now, in our map, if you see there is only one value called `category`. So, the `textfield` is used to select a value from the `dataSource` map and display it as text. The `valuefield` will hold the key from the map which you want to return as value if that field is selected.

Comment: Please add the full error log in the question. Also, please print out the values inside the `_myActivities` list. So that, we can check if it is proper or not. Sometimes, it so happens that the data is null or incorrect.

Comment: Preet Shah. I am getting the same error in the question. And when I print the _myActivities, I am getting the following result on the console. `[Necklace, Rings, Bracelet, Chain, Drops, Ear Rings]`

Comment: Replace `_myActivities.add(item.data()['category']);` with this: `_myActivities.add(item.data();`.

Comment: When I changed the code as you said, It worked but suddenly this error appeared - `The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("category")`

And this is the console result `[{category: Necklace}, {category: Rings}, {category: Bracelet}, {category: Chain}, {category: Drops}, {category: Ear Rings}]`

Comment: Update the question with the new code. I may not be able to help without it.

Comment: @AhamedAmeen, I have made the necessary changes to the answer, please check.

Comment: It worked!! I really appreciate your help. Thanks!. So we need to store the onSaved value in a separate variable. Is that correct?

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted so that others can answer other questions. Happy to help.